# How can i get an element from array by index using firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show the users elements from the array one after another when each time the user can exit or continue to the next element. The array is part of a document in firestore. How can i query firestore to retrieve specific element by index?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I query Firestore to retrieve specific element by index?

If you want to get a specific element of a field of type Array of a Firestore document, **you need to fetch the entire document**, get the value from this Array field (which is a [JavaScript Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)) and then extract the desired data as you would for any JavaScript Array.

There isn't any option, with the Client SDKs, to fetch only a subset of the document fields. It is possible with the REST API, but not with the Client SDKs.

So very concretely, you would as follows:

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        const arrayField = doc.data().arrayField; 

        // arrayField is a JavaScript Array, you can use any method or property  
        // e.g. get index 0
        const arrayFieldFirstElement = arrayField[0];

    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Comment: I hopped there will be an efficient solution to this, kind of ridicolous for google.
Thank you anyway!

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, if the way the JavaScript SDK works does not corresponds to your needs, you can use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/get) and the `mask` parameters.

Comment: If you go to the API explorer of the method from Renauds answer, you will see that there is a tab called Javascript. From there you can obtain the javascript code to call the api using the mask.